# Can a LAN adapter cause a whole home network to crash?

Tags: networking, router, dns, lan

I was searching for a LAN adapter on Amazon.

One of the reviews stated that this LAN adapter caused a crash of their home network. The router would restart a lot and the laptop wouldn't have an internet connection. Removing the adapter solved the problem.

In case you want to read the review, here it is (on German): https://www.amazon.de/gp/customer-reviews/R3P59KQU3K8MB2/

I am just wondering, how or if that could even be possible? Doesn't the LAN adapter just "convert" the signal and not mess with IPs? Shouldn't the router just not deliver the signal to a faulty LAN adapter instead of restarting itself?

Maybe the buyer had a bad router?

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want a USB device?  They tend to require more CPU time to service compared to a PCI or PCIe NIC.   If there are expansion slots in your device, then do consider using them.  Not much help on a modern laptop sadly.

Comment: Note that as shown in the answers below, it's possible, but without more details about the exact setup and what happened exactly, it is quite difficult to assign the blame in this specific situation to either the LAN adapter, the computer it was connected to (and any applications — or malware — it was running, or its network configuration), the router, cabling, switches or anything else in the vicinity.

Comment: I think the key thing to know, when looking at the answers, is that these devices are connected by pieces of copper, and are well behaved because all of the devices agree what voltages to apply to the copper, and when to do so.  When a device becomes ill-behaved, it can violate these "social contracts" between the devices and cause all sorts of problems.  Typically it won't cause lasting damage, but it can stop things up pretty good.

Comment: The reason for the USB device: I need an adapter for the Nintendo Wii (yes I am still using one) and the Wii can only have adapters with a specific chipset. But better safe than sorry, I buy another adapter now.

Comment: If that adapter sends out a payload which gains root access to your router and deletes the entire filesystem, then yes.

Comment: I remember one place I worked, one admin ordered a bunch of cheap Chinese network cards.  He tested each one individually in a machine and each worked.  When he deployed them, nothing worked.  Turns out they all had the same MAC address.

Comment: Back in the stone age I actually dealt with an ARCnet card that could take down the whole network.  It behaved itself fine so long as you didn't tighten down the mounting screw.  Once I finally figured it out I left the screw a little loose and it ran fine until the machine was retired.

Answer (score 63):

Yes, it's possible for an Ethernet device to sabotage the entire network. At work, a core switch died and started flooding the network with invalid Ethernet frames at ~700 MBits/s. This caused all PCs on the network to overload the CPU so much even moving the mouse no longer properly worked.

Of course, non-PC devices could be affected by problems like that as well.

Comment: If you have a bittorrent client running on a really slim router, with no regard for network capacity, the number of connections and packets can easily overwhelm the router and cause it to crash. This is a legit, functioning software, so I can imagine a bad device to do even worse.

Comment: It gets worse. An ethernet card could theoretically fail in a way that puts too much voltage on the pins. Short to mains should blow a fuse, but short to +5 will be a surprise for the home router.

Comment: Can confirm this answer as well as @Joshua .. once had a problem with a server that, when booted/rebooted, would cause an entire network segment outage because its onboard network card was shorted out on an IC level .. this was a dev server that was constantly rebooted (or crashed due to bug). Took nearly 3 weeks to make sure it wasn't a software problem (using good ol' oscilloscope) and eventually had to put in a PCI network card to solve the problem. Fun times that was.

Comment: Incorrect physical (layer 1) behavior is a problem too, of course, but it does not generally propagate through switches.

Comment: @Joshua: IEEE requires Ethernet to reject 1500V @50/60 Hz for safety reasons. Short to mains may trigger a GFCI on the mains side but the router ought to be fine. 5V DC shouldn't be an issue at all. Ethernet was not designed as consumer-level, cheapest-thing-that-barely-works electronics.

Comment: @MSalters *IEEE requires Ethernet to reject 1500V @50/60 Hz for safety reasons.* **1500V**?!?! It'd be difficult for a device to reject a voltage after that voltage destroyed it.  "I'm so sorry Mr. Lightning Bolt, but your voltage is too high so I must reject you" isn't about to stop that lightning bolt from [releasing the magic smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke) from any device it wants to.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Lightning bolts are 300 **million** volts. 1500 Volt is a perfectly manageable voltage. Old TV's generally used ten times higher voltages without destroying themselves. High-speed trains have 25000 Volt overhead wires, and those are hanging outside in the rain.

Comment: @MSalters So nothing bad would happen were I to plug a cat6 cable into an ethernet switch port at one end and into a 240V dryer outlet on the other end?  Ooooh-kay.  You first.

Comment: @AndrewHenle (et al.) [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27756/why-are-ethernet-rj45-sockets-magnetically-coupled)'s a nice discussion at electronics.se

Comment: @Joshua The "fuses" in twisted-pair Ethernet are the common-mode termination networks on non-PoE devices, and the windings of the isolation transformers (magnetics) are next in line. The terminations will open if there's an "uncommanded" potential applied differentially between the pairs. The windings will open if there's too high of a current flowing through a pair - that may be either a differential or a common mode current, since the terminations are applied to the winding's center tap. There are no actual fuses there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's how those things are tested, actually. You really need to do some measurements on an actual network card, draw out the schematic of the isolation circuit, and so on. Otherwise you'll be just appealing to emotion without any understanding of how this stuff works. Yes, it's possible to destroy things by applying said 240VAC in a way that wasn't meant to be survivable, but typical short-to-mains scenarios are entirely benign and usually the way the get noticed is when a human gets "zapped" by touching the jack, while the link otherwise functions normally.

Comment: @MSalters: This has been tested. It doesn't work too well. http://www.fiftythree.org/etherkiller/

Comment: @Joshua: That page is written for humor, and is conspicuously lacking in methodological details or empirical results. Most of the actual claims of destroyed devices are things like disk drives and video cards, which are not isolated in the way that Ethernet is required to be.

Answer (score 23):

Absolutely yes.

There are many ways an Ethernet device can kill a network, especially a network with low consumer-grade equipment.

It can spam out malformed packets, swamping the router.
It can have a MAC address that matches an existing device on the network. Yes, this should not be possible. Also YES, it can and does happen.)
It can have a null MAC address, and your network has a router or device that cannot work with this.
I have even encountered an Ethernet device that output 220V on a PoE line, toasting everything downstream!

If your network is managed by a real device, say a decent Cisco router that is correctly configured, it will simply detect and isolate the malfunctioning/misbehaving device. But at household level? Nope.

Comment: Meh, I've seen a whole company network taken down by one person who short circuited a dumb hub between two switch ports.  Not the fault of the hub, mind you, but even enterprise network equipment can't deal with everything.

Comment: @J... well it is supposed to be *network* not a **shrubbery**

Comment: I've seen a network taken down by someone confusing cables and connecting two ports of the same switch. The loop multiplied broadcast packets and slowly but surely overloaded most switches in the network. To be fair, the administrator had STP and related features disabled on all switches because the periodic packets annoyed him, but yes even something like this can bring a whole network down and it can take a while to find the cause.

Answer (score 5):

Possible, but quite unlikely.

On the other hand, I had a somewhat similar experience with rather poor quality router.

The router ran more or less normally over wifi (B/G), but plugging any 100MBps crashed the router at the first bulk download. The router simply overheated when pushed to its limits at 100MBps and ran more or less normally at the 18MBps that are the maximum for G-type wifi.

Forcing the connection to 10MBps made the connection stable until the router was replaced.

Comment: Additionally, poor cabling/patches/termination can cause issues too.  As do cabling loops and occasionally hosts with two interfaces on the same network (wired and wireless even)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, some combination of OS drivers and hardware chips cause issues, where the network adapter emits a network flood when the computer is put into sleep mode.

An example of this is: https://www.isc.upenn.edu/how-to/intel-i2xx825xx-network-card-network-flooding-issue-fix

In the above issue, the network adapter floods the network with IPv6 multicast traffic, and switches not supporting multicast will cause this to flood the whole network.

If a well known brand makes this mistake, what prevents a lesser known brand from making the same mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try it for yourself (you probably don't), there is a very simple recipe: Attach a patch cable as a loop between two free ports (there are typically 4 switched LAN ports on the back of a home router).

The first time a packet for a non-local device appears, it will start looping between the ports at max speed and get replicated to the other ethernet ports as well, resulting in a devastating packet storm on all ports.