# How I can fix my network connection where a single PC causes my network to go down?

Tags: windows-7, networking, gateway, connection-sharing, client-server

I have a network of computers connected to a switch. But my network goes down completely when I connect a specific computer, I connected a laptop to the same node and with the same cable and I had no problems.

The PC’s OS is Windows 7.

Below I will explain the steps I follow to get to my problem:

- I connect the old PC to the node.
- I turn on the PC.
- I check the connection and everything seems to be going well, it was even able to access shared folders.
- I try to install software in terminal mode that requires a connection to a server (the server works correctly for all Terminals).
- But during installation (specifically when it make the connection to the server) the pc freezes completely and the entire network goes down.

When I say that the network goes down, I mean that it assigns me the wrong IPs and gateways to all devices.

To repair it I have to disconnect the node and turn the switch off and turn on again.

*The terminal is win 7,server is win server 2012 r2, switch model tp link TL-SF1024D, I'm using the router's gateway that works as my DHCP server*

Comment: Please give more details about the operating systems of the PC and server, and the model of the switch. What is the DHCP server for the internal network, the router?

Comment: Windows 7 is dead and will not do updates.  Perhaps the update you are trying to install is falling victim to this

Comment: All Terminals are working properly, including Windows 7 Terminals

Comment: *All Terminals are working properly, including Windows 7 Terminals* This is clearly not true. Windows 7 has ZERO protection against newer attack vectors and it seems you've been a victim of one. Using ANY unsupported, unpatched, OS online is dangerous and irresponsible.

Comment: FYI, Windows  server 2012 r2 is also EoL since October. You need to upgrade EVERYTHING ASAP, end of story. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/windows-server-2012-r2-end-of-support . PS - The ESUs mentioned existed for Windows 7 as well but ended almost a year ago.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use them for, it matters if they have online access or not. If not, do what you want, no problems are expected unless you use external media carrying malware; if online then all bets are off. And your supposition is a *non sequitur*. And yes, I understand and speak Spanish fluently but this site's language is English only.

Comment: One possible cause of the issue: the PC causing the network crash is issuing the *wrong type of network packets*. See also https://superuser.com/questions/1633245/can-a-lan-adapter-cause-a-whole-home-network-to-crash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a LAN adapter cause a whole home network to crash?](https://superuser.com/questions/1633245/can-a-lan-adapter-cause-a-whole-home-network-to-crash) That said, use a current OS - Window 11 if the PC's can run it, or any of the Linux distros that are currently supported.